# Generic class initialization from protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have classes objects `JSONSerialization`. So my input is `[String: Any]` and from a documentation I know it may be either `NSNull`, `NSString` or `NSNumber`. So I've made a protocol:

```swift
protocol PlainValue { }
```

and all of those above conform to this protocol:

```swift
extension NSString: PlainValue { }
extension NSNull: PlainValue { }
extension NSNumber: PlainValue { }
```

Then I want to create a class storage that hold key-value like:

```swift
class KeyValue<T: PlainValue> {
    let key: NSString
    let value: T
    
    init(key: NSString, value: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

And want to use it like this:

```swift
func parse(json: [String: Any]) {
    ...
    if let value = json[key] as? PlainValue { // this should be `Any` but I want to check here if thats an PlainValue or embedded object
        let obj = KeyValue<PlainValue>(key: key, value: value) // this currently not working
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But my issue is how to declare this object creation on protocol level. If I do this like:

```swift
protocol PlainValue {
    func convert(key: NSString) -> KeyValue<PlainValue>
}
```

I'm getting error:

> Value of protocol type 'PlainValue' cannot conform to 'PlainValue'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Make sense, since I'm already in protocol declaration. So I have a feeling that maybe this should be declared on `KeyValue<T>` level? But I'm not sure if I'm on a right path for this, since I'm getting compilers error on every approach I'm trying to make. Can anyone point me into right direction how to make it working?

Approach that I feel like it's closest to working is:

```swift
extension NSNumber: PlainValue {
    func convert(key: NSString) -> KeyValue<NSNumber> {
        return KeyValue<NSNumber>(key: key, value: self)
    }
}
```

And similar for above on `NSString` and `NSNull`, but not sure how to declare this on protocol level to make this callable from my parsing function. Since

```swift
protocol PlainValue: JSONValue { 
    func convert(key: NSString) -> KeyValue<Self> // this claims that implementation does not match this declaration

    func convert<T: PlainValue>(key: NSString) -> KeyValue<T> // same as above

    associatedtype Object: PlainValue
    func convert(key: NSString) -> KeyValue<Object> // this is working! But... then I cannot check if value is PlainValue in my parsing function, because of `Protocol 'PlainValue' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A protocol cannot conform to another protocol, the generic type `T` in `KeyValue<T>` must be a concrete type.

An alternative is a protocol extension with an associated type

```
extension NSString: PlainValue { }
extension NSNull: PlainValue {  }
extension NSNumber: PlainValue {  }

protocol PlainValue {
    associatedtype ValueType : PlainValue = Self
    func convert(key: NSString) -> KeyValue<ValueType>
}

extension PlainValue where ValueType == Self {
    func convert(key: NSString) -> KeyValue<ValueType> {
        return KeyValue<ValueType>(key: key, value: self)
    }
}


class KeyValue<T: PlainValue> {
    let key: NSString
    let value: T
    
    init(key: NSString, value: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

---

```
let stringResult = "Foo".convert(key:"bar")
let numberResult = NSNumber(value:12).convert(key:"baz")
let nullResult = NSNull().convert(key:"buz")
```

Comment: thanks, that was an explanation that I was looking for! `associatedtype ValueType : PlainValue = Self` has done a trick! (sorry cannot upvote yet - I'm new here ;) )
`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly what you would like to achieve, but based on what you wrote, you don't necessarily need generics here. The code below would resolve your issue, if there are no other factors that make generics necessary in your situation. Also, this way you won't need to declare the object creation on the protocol level.

```
class KeyValue {
    let key: NSString
    let value: PlainValue

    init(key: NSString, value: PlainValue) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Your original example did not work because you needed a concrete type there that conforms to PlainValue. In swift, only concrete types such as struct/enum/class can conform to protocols. For example `let obj = KeyValue<NSString>(key: key, value: value)` would work there, while using PlainValue would not.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks! that compile, but tbf I'm also curious why declaring it like I was trying to do it's not working :)

Comment: As the compile error says "'PlainValue' cannot conform to 'PlainValue'". You need a type there that conforms to PlainValue. For example: let obj = KeyValue<NSString>(key: key, value: value) would work fine.

Comment: And the reason for the above is, that in swift only concrete types such as struct/enum/class can conform to protocols. That's why it will not work with PlainValue in your original example.